# How to add a loader (less-loader) to vite.js (vite.config.js)?

Tags: javascript, less, vite

I started using Vite.js and I want to use less files in my project, I didn't find a clear solution to add a loader, especially less-loader beceause I am using Ant Design v4.

I used :

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default {
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

but it doesn't work, and I tried :

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default {
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'less',
      transform(code, id) {
        if (id.endsWith('.less')) {
          return require('less').renderSync({ data: code }).css;
        }
      },
    },
  ],
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
    },
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

nothing works, I asked chatGPT but it gave me random solution and nones worked, any solution  or article to learn how to configure loaders in vite.js ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what are the problems you are facing but I tried these steps and it's working fine for me.

1. Installed `less` in the project
2. I added support for `math`, `relativeUrls` along with `javascriptEnabled`  in vite config

```
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        math: "always",
        relativeUrls: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true
      },
    },
  }
```

Here is code sandbox link of my basic setup of [`vite+reactjs+antd+less`](https://github.com/abhinavRai23/Vite-react-ant-design)

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/abhinavRai23/Vite-react-ant-design/main

Comment: For more information, I found details in [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions) documentation

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues with a dependency that uses a second styling dependency which is using .less files.

```
 No loader is configured for ".less" files: node_modules/second-dependency-style/src/button-style.less

node_modules/first-dependency/lib/button.js:
  require("second-dependency-style");
```

Sorry I cannot give the names of the dependency. It's an old internal dependency.